# Installing RSVG on a Mac

Tags: macos, svg

I've already installed rsvg-convert once in a Mac, but it was using `pkg-config`, and now I'm trying to insert RSVG inside my own app. RSVG has [many dependences](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Installing_librsvg), which probably should also be inside my app, but I'm not sure if that is going to work.

And before anyone says, yes, I've checked other possibilities: ImageMagick (not so configurable), qlmanage (horrible result), Inkscape (too heavy), mogrify (same then qlmanage), batik-rasterizer (doesn't support all the svg files and requires Java)... all of them has unsolvable problems, but I'm pretty sure that the RSVG problem can solved!

There is any RSVG bundle out there? There is any ready-to-go script to install RSVG without `pkg-config`? And if I would really need `pkg-config`, there is any way to install it in a temporarily folder, just to install RSVG and then disappear?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 34):

[Homebrew](http://brew.sh) provides formula for [librsvg](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/librsvg.rb). Install Homebrew and type

```
brew install librsvg
```

Comment: I need to put it inside my app. I can't install Homebew and download librsvg in all my users computers.

Comment: After running this command to have Homebrew install librsvg, I noticed that `rsvg` is not available (i.e. returns "command not found").

Comment: @SoaperGEM The command should be `rsvg-convert`.

Comment: as of 2021 - `brew install librsvg` works and brew install rsvg-convert is not found

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a standalone rsvg-converter](https://github.com/miyako/console-rsvg-convert) for the Mac.